# Size of pointer array inside Struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, sizeof

I have these 2 structs :

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int num;
    int score;
} player;

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    player *players;
} team;
```

I need to know the amount of elements stored per every `*players` inside my `team` struct.
Thanks!

Comment: Then create a struct member for that (of type `size_t`, perhaps).

Comment: The team struct just contains a pointer to a player. This could be the first player in an array of players or it could just be a single player. How many will depend on how many you allocate when you assign some memory to that pointer.

Comment: @Will, i alocate 22, but the program may or may not use 22, so, then I'll realloc that memory to the amount used, then, a function needs to print how many players there are per team, so, i need a way to know how many items there're in the array itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the 'sizeof'(a pointer pointing to an array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.  `players` is a pointer to N `player` instances.  It carries no more information than an address.  It is not an array; it is a pointer.

You will have to store the number of elements in the struct separately.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    player *players;
    size_t num_players;
} team;
```

On a side note, you had better hope that Jarrod Saltalamacchia never joins this team.

Comment: That side note! (I'd +1 this if I had any votes left for today.)

Comment: Jarrod Saltalamacchia?? Who is that and why does he suck?

Comment: @LefterisE: `char name[20];`

Comment: @H2CO3: Damn it all, I was editing! :D  I actually tried to find a name that was 20, but 21 was the best I could do.

Comment: the names are max 20 chars by specs, not my decission. When all works i'll change that to char *name and make it work properly, untill then, i just want it working

Comment: @Dunnow: Then your code is wrong.  The current max is 19.  C strings are null terminated.

Comment: Oh, I thought we didn't want him to join our team because he was terrible :p didn't know that we just can't fit his big-ass name in the string.

Comment: @Ed S, never worked with size_t before, is that like an integer value that I can +1 per every item entered?